# Haskell: FIFO monad

Tags: haskell, fifo

Is there a standard (or at least commonly used) package with a monad for FIFO queues?  I read about [this one](https://gist.github.com/1233293) in a paper a while ago, and I've used it a couple times, but I'd like to stop reimplementing wheels (it's fun, but unproductive).

Comment: related? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-queue

Comment: sclv: Extremely!  The difference seems to be the use of continuations rather than wrapping it in a monad.  Looks like I accepted Sjoerd's answer too soon.

Comment: Ok, I'm submitting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nifty version of corecursive queues on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-queue

I wouldn't call it standard by any means, but it certainly reflects a fair amount of work and testing.

The linked monad reader article is a really good read too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is. I would use a `State` monad with a [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) container as state.

Comment: I suppose - I'd just feel weird swapping O(1) for amortized O(1).

Comment: Definitely use `Seq`.  See http://johnlato.blogspot.com/2011/07/circular-buffers.html for more information.

Comment: After running some quick and dirty benchmarks based on @John L's blog post, it looks like the `Seq`-based version is at worst comparable in performance to the unnerving Ouroboros in rampion's gist. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if the latter couldn't be tweaked to have much better performance, but just using `Seq` is probably less hassle that persuading GHC to optimize away the entire queue.

Comment: On the other hand, the Ouroboros queue seemed to outperform John L's mutable vector implementation, which is pretty funny. Assuming I didn't completely screw up my benchmarking, I suspect the lesson to take from this is that mutability isn't magically faster, and clever algorithms are nice, but a finger tree written carefully by very smart people is probably better than anything quickly hacked together will ever be. ;]

Comment: @C.A.McCann - I was surprised enough by my results that I requested a code review on haskell-art of my mutable vector implementation, which led to some small performance gains but not near enough to outperform Seq.  I still think I must be overlooking something big, but nobody's found it yet.  Also, IIRC the Ouroboros was Okasaki's initial FIFO queue, so look there for an optimized version.  Seq's probably comparable though.

Comment: @John L: There have been multiple occasions where I've compared different implementations of something and found that a naive pure version easily outperformed a naive version based on mutable state, so I'm not actually surprised. Anyway, I expect the only way the Ouroboros would win is by virtue of GHC's aggressive whole-program optimizing, and I wouldn't expect Okasaki's implementation to be tailored to GHC, so I doubt that would help much.

Comment: Mutation with boxed data is expensive because of the generational GC.